# I want the HostStartTime column in descending order from CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the HostStartTime column in descending order from CTE

```
WITH FilterData
     AS (
     SELECT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(35), HostStartTime, 103)+' '+(CONVERT(VARCHAR(35), HostStartTime, 24))) HostStartTime,
        --stuff(stuff(reserve1,1,4,'****'),len(reserve1)-3,4,'****')
           stuff(reserve1, 5, 8, '********') AS CardNo,
           Reserve2 AS AccountNumber,
           (CASE
                WHEN HostResponse = 'Y'
                THEN 'SUCCESS'
                ELSE 'FAILURE'
            END) HostResponse,
           HostID
     FROM TBL_Host
     WHERE HostStartTime >= @i_StartDate
           AND HostStartTime <= @i_EndDate
           AND HostID = 'GENERATE_PIN'
     ORDER BY HostStartTime DESC)
     SELECT HostStartTime,
            isnull(CardNo, 'NA') CardNo,
            AccountNumber,
            HostResponse,
            HostID
     FROM FilterData
     ORDER BY HostStartTime DESC;
```

Comment: I am getting the following error"The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: That's because it doesn't even make sense to put `ORDER BY` inside a CTE.

Answer (score 2):

Since the original `HostStartTime` column is already datetime/timestamp, it should sort as a datetime properly.  A quick fix here might be to add that column to the select list of your CTE, and then use it to do the final ordering:

```
WITH FilterData AS (
    SELECT
        -- add the next line to your CTE
        HostStartTime AS HostStartTimeOrig,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(35), HostStartTime, 103) + ' ' +
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(35), HostStartTime, 24) AS HostStartTime,
        STUFF(reserve1, 5, 8, '********') AS CardNo,
        Reserve2 AS AccountNumber,
        CASE WHEN HostResponse = 'Y' THEN 'SUCCESS'
            ELSE 'FAILURE' END AS HostResponse,
        HostID 
    FROM TBL_Host
    WHERE HostStartTime BETWEEN @i_StartDate AND @i_EndDate AND
        HostID = 'GENERATE_PIN'
)

SELECT
    HostStartTime,
    ISNULL(CardNo, 'NA') CardNo,
    AccountNumber,
    HostResponse,
    HostID
FROM FilterData 
ORDER BY
    HostStartTimeOrig DESC;
```